# How to install 64bit version of mongodb on Raspbian?

Tags: raspbian, pi-3b+, mongodb, 64-bit

I was able to install the mongodb-server. However, if I run the mongo-shell with the command "mongo", I get some warnings.

**One of them concerns me:**

> NOTE: This is a 32 bit MongoDB binary. 32 bit builds are limited to
>   less than 2GB of data (or less with --journal).

I need my database to store more than 2GB data and should therefore install a 64-bit version of mongodb-server on my raspberry pi.

Does anybody know how I can install the 64-bit version of MongoDB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Raspbian is a 32-bit system, and is likely to remain so for several years yet.

You need to find an alternative 64-bit system (I think there are such systems but have no idea how usable they will be).